# Openshift overrides email header 'from', 'reply-to' fields. How to send email without having to use SendGrid nor other paid email service.?

Tags: python, django, email, openshift, mezzanine

I have django 1.6 and python 2.7 deployed on Openshift.  I notice that when the application sends emails out, Openshift overrides the email header by changing the '**From**' field to '**no-reply@rhcloud.com**' and ignore all '**Reply-to**' field that has been set in the application.

I have searched around and it seems like Openshift overrides the email header and recommendation is to use their email service partner which is NOT FREE.

Is there any other way to avoid this ie. deploy Django application on Openshift while still having the application sends email as per dictated in the program.  This exact program runs with no issues on test environment and localhost.

Any pointers are much appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I myself is looking for free SMTP library to just send emails. So far not much luck.

Tried java embedded SMTP library **Aspirin**. I am able to  send mails but not very comfortable working with it as I keep getting some unknown exceptions.

Apache James as another Java based SMTP server but don't think we can embed in the code yet.