# Send email from Openshift without no-reply@rhcloud.com

Tags: django, email, python-2.7, openshift

My Django application sends email out to users.  On localhost, it was using my gmail account that i set via settings.py.  However, when porting the app onto Openshift, all the headers were ignored.  Instead of using the application from, reply-to email addresses, email coming from application on Openshift is **FROM  no-reply@rhcloud.com and no Reply-to email address.**

Here is what I later found:

> All e-mails routed through our servers have their From header rewritten. This will continue to function this way until we support e-mail as an "official" feature. Relaying through an external mail server should not overwrite this header." by Sumana Annam, Red Hat, Inc.
>   https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/sending-email-from-jboss-by-defect-the-from-is-no-replyrhcloudcom

Does anyone find a way of sending email from Openshift where the email header does not get rewritten?

Greatly appreciate any help/direction.

Comment: If you use a service like SendGrid, Mandrill, Mailgun, etc. to send your emails, you can send emails through HTTP API calls, instead of STMP. Openshift wouldn't be able to rewrite/stop those

Comment: possible duplicate of [Openshift overrides email header 'from', 'reply-to' fields. How to send email without having to use SendGrid nor other paid email service.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757997/openshift-overrides-email-header-from-reply-to-fields-how-to-send-email-wi)

Answer (score 0):

The official answer is that you would need to use a third party library to remove the no-reply@rhcloud.com.  There is no way to change that header on email that is relayed through openshift's email servers.